# How to fix Rational Rhapsody error :"Current value is "VC11", but no Visual Studio installation was not found in the directory ""."

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

Im working on Windows 7, 64-bit and I'm trying to run Rational Rhapsody 8.0.5 for C++ with Visual Studio Professional 2013. After creating a simple coding example for a class, I tried to compile it, but I got the following error :

Current value is "VC11", but no Visual Studio installation was not found in the directory "".

Is there something wrong with my installation, or do I need an older version of Visual Studios? I've tried everything, but nothing I've done is working. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps to configure IBM Rational Rhapsody 8.x to use the Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 compiler, borrowed from [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21677103):

1. Install Rational Rhapsody 8.x and Microsoft Visual Studio 2013.
2. In `<RHAPSODY _ROOT>\Share\Properties`, set the factoryC++.prp file to read/write permissions and open the file in a text editor.
3. Under the metaclass sections: MSVC, MSVCDLL, MSVCStandardLibrary add the string `VC12` to the Property `IDEVersion`. For example,

   ```
   Metaclass MSVC
   Property IDEVersion Enum "VC9,VC10,VC11,VC12" "VC10"
   ```
4. Browse to the `<RHAPSODY _ROOT>\Share\etc` folder and open the `msvcmake.bat` file
5. Copy the line

   ```
   if "%4"=="VC11" set VS_PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\
   ```

   and paste a new line beneath with the following changes

   ```
   if "%4"=="VC12" set VS_PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\6
   ```
6. Copy the line

   ```
   @echo VC11 - Visual Studio 2012
   ```

   And paste with changes

   ```
   @echo VC12 - Visual Studio 2013
   ```
7. Open Rational Rhapsody8.1 and load a sample project. For example,
   `<RHAPSODY _ROOT>\Samples\CppSamples\Dishwasher`
8. Select the Project’s **Active Component/Configuration**. For example, **EXE** and **Host**
9. Double-click the **configuration** in the browser and open the **features** window. Select the **Properties** tab and find the `CPP_CG::MSVC::IDEVersion` property. Switch the value to `VC12`
10. Run the **Build Framework** command in the **Code** menu. You will see a lot of deprecation warnings.
11. Once this is completed you can then build and run the sample project via the **Code > Generate/Make/Run** command

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2013 is not supported.  VS2012 is the latest that it supports.
I'm assuming you know how to select your version of visual studio within Rhapsody.